# How to calculate $P(|X|>1.6)$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable that is uniformly distributed on $[-2,-1],[1,2]$.
Calculate :$$P(|X|>1.6)$$
So far, I calculated two options:
1. $P(1.6< X\leq 2)$ = $0.4$
2. $P(-2\leq X<-1.6) = 0.4$
and my thought was to do $0.4+0.4 =0.8$ but the real answer is $0.4$. Why is that?

Comment: Becaause the value of  the density function over the two intervals is 1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

$P(|X|<1.6) = P(X\lt-1.6) + P(X\gt1.6)$

$P(X\lt-1.6) = \frac{(-1.6-(-2))}{2} = 0.2\tag1$

$P(X\lt1.6) = \frac{1.6-1+(-1-(-2))}{2} =\frac{(1.6-1+1)}{2}= 0.8$

$P(X\gt1.6) = 1-P(X\lt1.6) = 1-0.8 = 0.2\tag2$

Adding (1) and (2)

$P(|X|<1.6) = 0.4$

Answer (score 2):

The two options you have calculated are incorrect. The sample size for both should be $|[-2, -1] \cup [1,2]| = 2$, rather than 1 as it appears you have taken.

So we now have the probabilities of the options as

1. $|2-1.6|\over2$ = $0.2$
2. $|-2+1.6|\over2$ = $0.2$

So the answer is indeed $0.4$.

(Perhaps you tried to find the probability with the sample space for the $(1.6,2]$ as only $[1,2]$ and similarly for the negative bit)